# Android Studio "The following classes could not be found" error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using Android Studio, freshly downloaded yesterday, and whenever I attempt to use the `<shape>` class, I get an error.

The code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

The problem:

```
Rendering Problems
The following classes could not be found:

- shape (Fix Build Path)
- solid (Fix Build Path)

Tip: Try to build the project
```

None of the solutions in a multitude of other questions on stackoverflow have helped - I am in desperate need of an actual solution to my problem. What am I doing wrong? The `build` in `Tip: Try to build the project` is a link, but whenever I click it, *nothing happens*. On the other hand, when I click on `(Fix Build Path)`, I get taken to a new window which shows tabs, including `properties`, `signing`, `flavors`, `build types` and `dependencies`; I have **absolutely no idea what any of this means**. Please help!

Comment: where did you put it ?

Comment: are you placing this file inside res folder?

Comment: @acostela Location of `activity_main.xml` - `MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml`

Comment: In layouts you can only use layouts types. For shape you must put them in drawable, and after that call them in the layout. I will post you an answer with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the shape class inside drawable and after that use them inside your layout. i.e.

/drawable/buttonshape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#34B8C7"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
```

After that inside your layout you can declare your button and tell it to use that shape in the following way.

```
      <Button
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            ......
            ......
            />
```